# Are all of the components on the exposed circuit board of a hard drive necessary?

Tags: hard-drive

So, this may seem like a stupid question, but are all of the components on the exposed circuit board on a hard drive necessary?

I ask this because of a weird situation I had with a hard drive. I got a used 360GB sata1 3.5inch Seagate drive from a friend. He was scrapping an old tower for parts, and he sold me the hard drive.

One day, I had the drive hooked up to a Sata to USB adapter so I could format it. While it was connected, smoke started emanating from the board. Since I didn't have a technician on call, and I was not particularly invested in the well being of the hard drive, I did what seemed like a sensible thing at the time: I took a Flathead screwdriver, and pried off the part that was smoking. It was a little black square. After doing that, the hard drive stopped smoking, and actually continued to work. 4 years later, the drive is still going strong in an HTPC I made for my parents.

I was under the impression that a circuit board was like a closed system, and frying/destroying any part of the board would destroy the whole thing. But that is clearly not the case here. **How is that possible? Are not all of the components neccesary for the drive to function?** Is my drive now operating in some diminished capacity, or is the loss of the smoking part completely inconsequential?

Comment: For anyone to have the remotest clue what part you might have removed, you would need to post a picture of the board.

Comment: In my IT engineer I had to often damage faulty HDDs (removed from bank PC, so we had to render them unusable). So I speak from experience that it's not as easy as is described here... Of course, we did it to damage data, so best way we found out was to drill 2 holes: 1 through casing to disable motor and damage plates, second to damage IC responsible for data integrity...
just "taking flathead screwdriver and Prying off" anything sounds wrong. It's not as easy as it sounds, and more often than not you have to unscrew PCB and flip it to just get to circuitry...

Comment: @AcePL,  I think we all thought that "taking a flathead screwdriver and prying it off" sounded wrong, but for entirely different reasons.

Comment: Well, I sometimes think of something stupid and then I actually find out that it really is... ;) Users can complicate anything and then my literalness takes over.

Answer (score 0):

ok, its late so forgive me if I ramble.

The first thing you need to know, is that electricity passing through a circuit is like water in a pipe. it is drawn from the source, through the circuit pathways in an entirely dumb fashion. each pipe the power is drawn into doesn't know that other pipes exist; there is no intelligence to it at all. it just goes where it is drawn. That means that if one pathway is damaged, the others won't know anything about that.

The second thing to consider is that electricity is an inherently analog phenomenon. I won't get into volts/amps/ohms/etc, but every one of them varies from nanosecond to nanosecond. a component that handles electricity has to take power that has attributes within a range of values. eg: a circuit designed to channel 3.3 volts will rarely be at exactly 3.30. it might be 3.31 or 3.43, or even 1.29. Every component has a tolerance range within which it will operate. if the power is out of tolerance, the component may not work right, may work fine, or may damage itself. Circuit pathways are essentially a conductive medium which connect primitive components like transistors, capacitors, resistors, etc, and more complex components like IO buses to RAM, or a ROM, or a daughter board. All of these components work in different ways, with different requirements, tolerances, and risks if those tolerances are not met.

For instance, Capacitors are vulnerable to being fried by too much power, or may simply explode because they were unable to release the hydrogen that is the natural output of their chemical composition. One or two bad caps on a motherboard usually won't cause it to catastrophically fail, but depending on the design, downstream components may not receive all the voltage they want. A downstream transistor may read a low-power signal as a 0, when it was really supposed to be a 1, which may or maynot make an important pathway inaccessible. A pathway connecting to the 7th bit of a 16bit ROM might burn out. in that case, any reads off that rom would work fine except that the 7th bit might always be 0, or might always be 1.

Third, note that there are many ways to design a circuit with a specific function, and the companies that produce ROM resident code like BIOSes, Firmware, or even operating systems often have no real idea about the exact implementation of the circuit on which it has been installed. if one or a few pathways are not receiving power when maybe they should, its as likely as not that the ROM will never know.

Once again, the power is just like water in a pipe. When you start to run out of hot water to draw, the pressure drops. an explosion at the water plant may cause every tap in your house to burst. or it might just burst the sink in the guest bedroom. But ask yourself; if you shut off the valves in the guest bathroom, will your kitchen sink still work? will the kitchen sink know that the guest bathroom is out of order, and refuse to work as a result? Since the kitchen plumbing probably does not rely on the guest bathroom, it will continue to work fine. But if you have a relative in town, they'd better not use the restroom.

Engineers, both in hardware and software, do their best to defensively design circuits to be as dependable in the long term as is cost effective, so many minor issues can be corrected. The causes and effects are so small and specific that often damage can go unnoticed, or may result in occasional random glitches or bizarre log messages; or it may introduce a fatal flaw that prevents a primary function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the components exposed in a hard drive are neccessary - otherwise the manufacturer would not have paid to have them there - but to be clear - "neccessary" here implies working reliably and playing with unknowns - which means that the system may be overspecced for some needs.

The part which blew up quite probably related to filtering/controlling the input of the device - and in fact the part probably was neccessary - in fact a BETTER part was neccessary otherwise it would not have blown up while doing its job.    You also got lucky that this part did not "take out the entire system".  That you have not had another power event which caused further damage - as it is reasonable to assume the power regulation circuitry is most likely fried - is also lucky.

Of-course, if you are running a very good case power supply which can deliver very clean voltage and handle current bursts and filter noise, you can argue that some of the circuitry is not neccessary - similarly you could "get by" with simpler logic circuitry, smaller controller memory etc - this could produce a working hard drive, but not one which works as well for enough people that the extra cost of the parts is worth it.